# Why is the default port for my local react application 8080?

Tags: reactjs, http, webserver, port, single-page-application

When I create a local react application, the default url is

```
http://localhost:8088/
```

But should it not better be port 80, since port 80 is the port for web server that listening to http requests?

Comment: I'm sorry by the way. It seems I've misread the 8088 for 8080.. For 8088 I would look at the answer from this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/398462/what-is-radan-http/398464
It seems that the port once WAS vendor specific but is now publicly used. In terms of what works it doesn't really matter which port it is, as long it isn't used by anything else. But it's always good to use standard ports. For example for https servers/services that would be 80 or 8080, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit: 26th August 2020]**

I'm sorry by the way. It seems I've misread the 8088 for 8080.. For 8088 I would look at the answer from this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/398462/what-is-radan-http/398464
It seems that the port once WAS vendor specific but is now publicly used. In terms of what works it doesn't really matter which port it is, as long it isn't used by anything else. But it's always good to use standard ports. For example for http servers/services that would be 80 or 8080, etc...

**[Original Answer]**

To answer I qoute from the GRC:

> port 8080 was often chosen as a convenient place to host a secondary or alternate web server.

For more information about that, here is the link to the definition. Look under "**Background and Additional Information:**"

https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer. still confused, so why we need to use a secondary port? why not use port 80 directly?